# Using temp tables in SSIS

Tags: sql-server, ssis, temp-tables

I've created an ADO.NET connection manager, and a DataReader source with the following SQL Command:

```
select 
   'test' as testcol
INTO
   #tmp

select * from #tmp
```

If I click the refresh button in the DataReader component, I get SqlException "Invalid object name #tmp".  The SQL statment itself is clearly valid and executes properly in sql server management studio. I've also tried setting DelayValidation on the connection manager, to no avail.

Comment: I have not worked with SSIS. But, is it possible that #tmp is not being created due to permissions to the user/context using which the SSIS task can run?

Comment: Not sure, but I would think I'd get a permissions error if that were the case.

Answer (score 2):

is the error on the INSERT or the SELECT?

if you are issuing only one command that contains both the INSERT and SELECT, try putting a semicolon before the SELECT.

**EDIT** after OP comment
encapsulate all the logic within a stored procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE YourProcedureName
AS
select 
   'test' as testcol
INTO
   #tmp

select * from #tmp

GO
```

the have your application run this single SQL command:

```
exec YourProcedureName
```

**EDIT** after next OP comment

OP doesn't say which SQL Server version they are using, if 2005 or up, try a CTE:

```
;with CTEtemp as
(
select 
   'test' as testcol
)
select * from CTEtemp
```

Comment: Semicolon doesn't appear to help.

Comment: True, a stored proc would be so much easier.  Unfortunately our server group prevents me from creating stored procedures on that sql server, and if I put a stored proc on another server, the cross server joins would be sub-optimal.

Comment: Fortunately, I was able to rework the query to not require temp tables, but I'm still interested in how one would go about doing this in SSIS because this seems like a definite shortfall if you ask me.

Comment: In case anyone comes along with the same issue, I was able to get my stored proc with temp tables to play nicely by putting SET FMTONLY OFF at the top of the proc, just before my SET NOCOUNT ON statement.  It bypassed the 'invalid object' errors and allowed me to pull metadata directly into my OLEDB source.

Answer (score 0):

Why couldn't this be replaced with a "SELECT 'test' as testcol"? The SSIS query parser may be having trouble with it because there's a temp table involved and it expects a single statement, not an actual SQL script. Or, if what you're sharing above is only an example for illustration, maybe something like this:

```
SELECT *
  FROM (SELECT 'test' AS testcol)
```

Can you elaborate on what you're trying to accomplish here and, if it is, why the temp table is required?

Comment: This was just a simplified example.  In my real situation I require the temp table, but I used this example for simplicity.

Answer (score 0):

Use `sp_executesql`

Your command would become

```
exec sp_executesql @statement=N'
select 
   ''test'' as testcol
INTO
   #tmp

select * from #tmp'
```

You must use nvarchar string (hence the N), and escape single quotes by doubling them.

I had the same problem as you and this is how I just fixed it.

Comment: Here lies an answer which didn't work for me despite my best hopes. It makes no sense that it didn't work. But then again, that's why I do my ETL in raw C# with SqlBulkCopy and other helper functions these days. SSIS is too much bloat for a coder. I might release my ETL library one day on NuGet.